# Python MySQL Insert or Update variables

Tags: python, mysql, insert, sql-update

I am migrating from sqlite to mysql and got stuck with an Insert or Update statement. I understand that mysql uses ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Here is what i have got so far, but it won´t update, it stops at the first duplicate entry.

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
 reader.next()
 for row in reader:
  row[8]=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[8],"%d.%m.%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (Umsatz,Waehrung,Kundenname,UstID,BUKey,Kundenkonto,Rechnungsnummer,Belegfeld2,Rechnungsdatum,Sachkonto,Belegtext,MwSt) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s); ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE", row)

db.commit()
```

Comment: Does it say about any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), your query will not work as you intent it to (look at the semicolon before ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE).

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (       
  Umsatz,
  Waehrung,
  ...
) VALUES (
  %s, 
  %s,
  ...
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  -- here you need to specifiy what to update on duplicate key, see documentation
;
```